# Additional defines when cross compiling QT

Tags: c++, qt, embedded, cross-platform

At this time I am working on an embedded device and i require to
compile Qt library. Additionally I need to add some defines, most important is `QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION`. Could someone help me out here, where would be the accurate location to place this define before compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `-DQT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION` to `configure`.